# update nm-applet settings on Ubuntu command line

Tags: networkmanager

I am running Linux on VMWare on MAC. I am using Dongle to connect to external networks.

I have created a hotspot, which works perfectly fine. The only problem is that when I stop hotspot my `nm-applet` disappears.

I load it from command line again, but `Enable Wireless` settings are turned off. I have to check it manually to get connected to my default WiFi network again.

Is there a way to change the `nm-applet` settings from command line?

Answer (score 4):

Recent versions of the `network-manager` package on Ubuntu should provide the `nmcli` utility - which should enable you to do what you want from the command line. I'm not sure exactly the equivalent to the GUI settings you are describing, but probably

```
nmcli nm wifi on
```

If you need to re-enable networking as a whole (rather than just the `wifi` component), then that would be

```
nmcli nm enable true
```

There are other command options for bringing up / taking down individual connections (`con` objects) and interface devices (`dev` objects) - see the `nmcli` manpage for details.

For lower-level control, it's possible to interface to `network-manager` via `dbus`, however the `dbus` APIs and tools are quite complex IMHO and clear documentation is not always easy to find.

Comment: Problem is that I cannot change GUI Settings for nm-applet. Other settings are working fine